# Filling a pre-allocated string of fixed size passed as an argument in C

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

I need to get a fixed length name from a 3rd party developer in a clean way that (hopefully) doesn't require any allocation on their side, and is checked well by the compiler.

I provide a prototype like this:

```
void getName(char name[9]);
```

And they would write a function something like this:

```
void getName(char name[9]) {
   strncat(_name, "Hello World", 8);
}
```

Then I call it (on my side) sort of like this:

```
char buf[9];
*buf = '\0';
getName(buf);
doSomethingWith(buf);
```

It compiles and seems to work, but I'm not sure its the best way to handle this.

Any advice?

Edit:  To clarify, the name string is used as an identifier in a packed binary save file. It needs to be exactly 8 ASCII 8-bit chars.

I wonder now if I should just receive any string and truncate it on my side. I was hoping the compiler would help instead of this being a runtime check.

Comment: I'd expect a function called `getName` to return something, rather than set something. I'd call it `init_name` or `set_name` or something. If it's a getter, I'd either have it return a newly allocated (heap memory) `char *`, or return a `const char *` string constant

Comment: The major caveat is that `getName( char name[9] )` does in no way or form ensure that `getName()` can only be called with a nine-character buffer. *Any* `char *` will satisfy the compiler, even an uninitialized one, leading to invalid memory access.

Comment: @DevSolar Aha. Then that is a problem. It needs to be exactly 8 ASCII cars. It's used as an identifier in a binary save file.

Comment: You could guarantee this by declaring a struct with an appropriately sized `char[]` member and passing *that* around. And even then there is no protection against someone just casting `void*` to that struct. C is not a language of guarantees. It's the language of "follow the rules or this will crash". Document the length requirements and write, "otherwise, behaviour is undefined". That's the way of C.

Comment: @DevSolar Heheh. I'm all too aware of that. Thanks, this does seem like a viable option.

Comment: @DevSolar I liked this solution at first but then I realized that all it does is ensure (kind of) that you will get a string stored in a buffer of the correct size, it does not mean the string in the buffer will be of the correct size.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to do this, especially the "checked well by the compiler" part. So then the question becomes what are the ways the 3rd party code can (or is likely to) mess up and what's the bet way to handle them. For example, if the name you get is too long you can truncate it, if the name is too short maybe you can pad it. Of course, there are many other ways for the 3rd party code to mess up, it could crash for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the name is a static string. In this case the function could look like below, where no additional data copy is required:

```
const char* getName(void)
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

...

```
const char* const pName = getName();
```

Alternatively:

```
void getName(FUNCPTR func)
{
    func("Hello World");
}
```

where the `void func(const char* const pName)` is implemented at your side. Then you also don't need to allocate/copy data.

Comment: Yes. You should avoid using an array with an explicit size unless you know for sure what size data is being copied into it. The original example results in a buffer overflow.

Comment: I need an exactly 8 character string. It's used as an identifier saved in a packed data file.

Comment: You in any case need to check whether the string contains 8 characters (it may contain less in fact), right? From that perspective I personally see no benefit of using the explicit size array in this case, only more complexity and risks of a buffer overflow as mentioned @o_weisman in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Your first job is to agree the data type of the returned string.

Although it's tempting to use `char*`, you ought not to since the type of `char` is not sufficiently well-defined by the standard (could be unsigned, signed 2's complement or signed 1's complement). If you're not careful the behaviour of your program could be undefiend if you mix up your types.
So you ought to decide on a type and use `#DEFINE CharType` accordingly.

Then as for the function itself, don't rely on the 3rd party to allocate memory unless you call their library to release that memory. Your C runtime might use a different allocation system to theirs. In order to address this common issue, a sort of convention has grown up: if you pass `NULL` for the output buffer then the 3rd party function should return the length of the buffer required. Then you allocate the memory yourself with the required length, and call the function a second time with the size of the allocated buffer explicitly sent. In that mode, the function returns the length of the allocated string as well as the result populated into the buffer.

Putting this all together, a good prototype would be

`SizeType getName(CharType* buffer, SizeType length);`

where `SizeType` is again agreed upon between you and the 3rd party. Broadly speaking, this is how the Windows API works.

Comment: It being a fixed size of 8 chars is a requirement. 8 bytes of ASCII character to be precise. It is used as an identifier in a packed binary save file.

Comment: @SamWashburn Maybe you can truncate or pad to make it 8 bytes. Why does it have to be ASCII?

Comment: @Stuart I can truncate and pad, yeah.  I was just hoping to have something that wasn't a runtime check which could be caught by the compiler because the use of a string that is too long is likely an error on the 3rd party's part.  As for ASCII, it's just easier to deal with.  Theoretically it's possible, for example with UTF-8, to have a string that is 9 bytes long and the last char is two bytes which would be chopped in half.